# Convert from char to Num a list of variables

Tags: sas

I use the following code to add empty columns to my data set. How can I specify that they must be numeric instead of character?

Thank you in advance

> ```
>        data mydb;
>          set all;
>            array c{54} $100;
>        run;
> ```

I would like columns from c1 to c54 to be numeric. By default they are char.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. By default they are numeric. You set them to character with a length of 100 with the `$100` part of your Array Statement.

Simply do this to make them numeric.

```
data mydb;
   set all;
   array c{54};
run;
```